# Hoeffding's lemma for unbounded r.v with bounded exponential map

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics

Let $X$ be a real r.v with $E[e^{\lambda X}] < \infty $ for all $\lambda \in [-c,c]$. 
Is it possible to get an Hoeffding's lemma like bound on $E[e^{\lambda(X-EX)}]$. That is, an upper bound: $$E[e^{\lambda(X-EX)}] \le e^{s\lambda^2},\;\;\;\forall \lambda \in [-c,c],$$ for some fixed constant $s>0$.

Comment: What can $s$ depend on?

Comment: $s$ is a fixed positive constant not depending on $\lambda$.

Comment: $s$ needs to depend on $X$ since you can have $E[e^{cX}]$ arbitrarily large while $EX=0$.  For nonnegative $X$ you can take $s=(E[e^{cX}]-1-cEX)/c^2$, I think, I didn't check very carefully.

Comment: If s is allowed to depend on c, then there is no meaning for lambda^2 for large \lambda, and near 0 the behavior is always quadratic, so the answer is "of course". If s is not allowed to depend on c, it should be easy to construct counter examples.